# jquery.validate.js não funciona sem form-group (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, validação

A validaçao do `jquery.validate.js` só funciona quando o `input` esta dentro de 
`<div class="form-group">`, por exemplo se eu coloco o código:

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
         <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
             <input id="id_codigo_empresa" name="codigo_empresa" 
                  type="number" class="form-control" maxlength="6"
                          placeholder="Código da entidade" required>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Se deixar o `input` vazio e clicar no botão <kbd>submit</kbd> ele não mostra a mensagem `'Campo requerido'` na tela, porém se eu faço:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
             <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
                 <input id="id_codigo_empresa" name="codigo_empresa"
                      type="number" class="form-control" maxlength="6" 
                              placeholder="Código da entidade" required>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Acrescentando uma `div` com `form-group` funciona, mas não quero usar o `form-group` porque ele tira a formatação do campo e dai muda o design.

Tem alguma forma de usar o validador sem o `form-group`?

*Só pra complementar, ele valida, porém não exibe a mensagem sem o `form-group`.*

se acrescento as minhas modificações do estilo com o form group a coisa fica meio bizarra. abaixo imagem do campo com o form-group e sem o ele, vejam que o input ficou quadrado e sem bordas e como tinha diminuído o margin-botton o label do erro fica por traz do input.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem como disponibilizar um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) de exemplo usando essas classes do bootstrap com o validator?

Comment: Você disse: "**_Só pra complementar, ele valida, porém não exibe a mensagem sem o `input-group`._**", você já verificou o que essa classe faz nos campos? Da uma verificada no `arquivo.css`, onde tem essa classe, tenta **inspecionar os elementos da página** (**F12**), para ver como está sendo montada a página.

Comment: ao invés de você tentar tirar a div form group, porque não tenta dar um !important no seu próprio estilo do css? dessa forma o form não ficara desconfigurado como você disse

Comment: @BrunoCastro , tentei mas fica meio bizarro, postei uma imagem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `.validate` do plugin deve ser usado no `ID` do formulário, conforme [Fiddle de exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/p02hqnw9/2/).

---

*Aqui está o `Snippet` usado, porém está com erro no script, mas é o mesmo código do [Fiddle de exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/p02hqnw9/2/).*

```js
$("#formulario").validate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="inner-addon left-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>
      <form class="cmxform" id="formulario" method="get" action="">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Por favor entre com seu nome, email e um comentário.</legend>
          <p>
            <label for="cname">Nome (Requer, no mínimo 2 caracteres)</label>
            <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input id="id_codigo_empresa" name="codigo_empresa"
               type="number" class="form-control" maxlength="6"
               placeholder="Código da entidade" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="cemail">E-Mail (requerido)</label>
            <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="curl">URL (opcional)</label>
            <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="ccomment">Seu comentário (requerido)</label>
            <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
          </p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Utilizei o `jquery.validate.js` do site [jqueryvalidation.org](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), não sei se é o mesmo que você usou, mas no [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p02hqnw9/2/) está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: funcionou o seu código, porém me deparei com outro problema, estou usando o form-wizard do bootstrap ( <fieldset>), aquele que tem abas e ele ja tem um botão de 'proximo' e anterior, então eu só dou um submit na ultima etapa. vc acha que eu devo parar de usar esse form-wizard?

Comment: Ele (**Form-Wizard**) está dando algum problema? Se não, não vejo problemas de continuar usando.

Comment: Se a resposta ajudou, não esqueça de marcar como correta e avaliar ;)

Comment: já marquei como correta e confirmei os 50 pontos, isso me ajudou, obrigado. Vou só ver como posso fazer para o botão próximo chamar esse evento, na verdade vejo que ele valida, porém não aparece a mensagem.

Comment: Considere [criar outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) para resolver esse problema em específico ;)

Answer (score -1):

Simples, o `jquery.validade` posiciona os elementos utilizando `position:absolute` portanto para um funcionamento coerente será necessário que ele esteja enclausurado em um elemento com `position:relative`.

Para resolver bastaria que a `div.inner-addon` esteja com o seguinte atributo:

```
.inner-addon {
    position: relative
}
```

Comment: fiz como você mostrou, acrescentei esse style a .inner-addon mas não funcionou, tentei em outras divs, mas nada, fiz uma edição na minha pergunta, o correto é form-group e não input-group.